# LinkedIn API call with url encoded

Tags: go, linkedin-api

For example, if I make a call to:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name)
```

It should work fine, but if the URL encoded (and it should be) like this:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:%28id,first-name,last-name%29
```

I get this error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
    <status>404</status>
    <timestamp>1423577265744</timestamp>
    <request-id>6B2UQSA25W</request-id>
    <error-code>0</error-code>
    <message>[invalid.property.name]. Couldn&#39;t find property with name {:%28id,first-name,last-name%29} in resource of type {Person}</message>
</error>
```

How can you deal with that?
Currently I cannot change the code because my language (Golang btw) do very properly encode this with standar package. Here is my code:

```
r, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name)", nil)
r.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+respBody.AccessToken)
resp, err = http.DefaultClient.Do(r)
```

Do you have solution for this issue except rewrite std lib code?

Some what face with the same issue since 2013 here https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/edit-i-dont-way-uris-look

Comment: Please show us your Go code calling the URL.

Comment: OK, here is it http://pastebin.com/tV1yWUWu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the URL Opaque field to the path after creating the request:

```
r, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.linkedin.com", nil)
if err != nil {
  // handle error
}
r.URL.Opaque = "/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name)"
r.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+respBody.AccessToken)
resp, err = http.DefaultClient.Do(r)
```

The [URL type](http://godoc.org/net/url#URL) documentation describes how to do this.